# Bridge pins that dont fit in

Tags: acoustic-guitar

I definitely do not want to break the bridge and even if the bridge pins are sticking out a few millimeters, that will make  palm muting irritating. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently slightly smaller (diameter) pins are available.

Use 100-120 grit sandpaper to rub the pins' diameter smaller.

Open up the bridge holes very slightly, using the next size drill bit, or preferrably a tapered reamer, checking very carefully and often.